# Error: Cannot find module on visual studio code (node server.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio

I'm working on a project and I need to make the node server.js work first before I proceed to check it elsewhere. I am experiencing this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\xxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxx\server.js'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
   at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
   at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
   at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
   at bootstrap_node.js:496:3
```

here are my codes for server.js

```
"use strict"

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const routes = require('./routes/RouteFood');

var app = express();
var host = "127.0.0.1";
var port = 8080;
var startPage = "home.html";

app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.use(express.static('./public/js'));
app.use(express.static('./public/css'));
app.use(express.static('./public/images'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

routes.routeFood(app);

function gotoIndex(req, res) {
   console.log(req.params);
   res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + startPage);
   res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "food.html");
}

app.get('/food.html', gotoIndex);

var server = app.listen(port, host, function() {
   var host = server.address().address;
   var port = server.address().port;

console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});
```

Can someone help me to solve this? and tell me what the error is?

Comment: how are you calling the server.js? From vs?

Comment: Check the location of your command line.